# Navigating Up with the App Icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am implementing up navigation in my action bar with the 'back' arrow.
I have been doing this as follows:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and declaring the parentactivity in the manifest manually.  The problem is, in my app for some activities there maybe many routes to the destination activity.

I have been researching this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

and to quote

> Or, override getSupportParentActivityIntent() and
>   onCreateSupportNavigateUpTaskStack() in your activity. This is
>   appropriate when the parent activity may be different depending on how
>   the user arrived at the current screen. That is, if there are many
>   paths that the user could have taken to reach the current screen, the
>   Up button should navigate backward along the path the user actually
>   followed to get there.
>
> The system calls getSupportParentActivityIntent() when the user
>   presses the Up button while navigating your app (within your app's own
>   task). If the activity that should open upon up navigation differs
>   depending on how the user arrived at the current location, then you
>   should override this method to return the Intent that starts the
>   appropriate parent activity.

The only problem is I don't know what to override it with to get the current parent activity.  Has anyone used this previously?  I'd appreciate advice

If anyone could help me on how to do this I'd greatly appreciate it, I'm not as suggested using it as a back button. I'm just trying to overwrite the up button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh...for anyone who might need a more helpful answer than those provided...
here is what I have done

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.animator.close_slide_in, R.animator.close_slide_out);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

so in the case of android.r.id.home that's where you put your required action.  In my case I just wanted to finish the current activity

I hope that's of some use to somebody out there

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html), you should not make the up button behave in different ways everytime. That is the way the back button should work.

Comment: thanks, that's not what I was asking...as per http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home you can over ride...as I explained in my question, that is of no benefit to me...thank you.